# Replying to people with "special" names, causes HTML entity to be inserted

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, unicode

Problem can be seen here: [Do we really need the [executable] or [exe] tags?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8160/do-we-really-need-the-executable-or-exe-tags#comment21005_8170)

Comment: I think you should state what the specific problem is: the user name “ṧнʊß” appears in a comment as “ṧнʊ&#223;”. The odd thing is that “ß” is the most ordinary of the characters in the name.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. In addition to *that*, the "ṧ" isn't displayed at all on my phone actually.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I heard my name... Yeah... I'm strange like that... ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Same, i didn't know why, I use Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next update (1.0.44), thanks!